# Detect keypress when Gtk.Entry is in focus

Tags: python, gtk, keypress, gtk3

I was trying to make a Entry widget that clears it's content when Esc is pressed.
Here's what I've tried -

```
class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        editor = Gtk.Entry()
        self.add(editor)
```

I don't know what to connect the widget to. Esc is a keypress but the keypress should occur when the entry is in focus. I am totally lost.

Please help me make a entry that clears when Esc is pressed and it's in focus.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could connect `Gtk.Entry` to either `"key-press-event"` or/and `"key-release-event"` to receive notification about the key being pressed or released for the entry widget. The callback will be called when entry receives key-press/release events for which it has to be in focus. To to check if `Escape` key has been pressed you can make use of the *event* passed to the callback. You can check the keyval (which is associated with `Gdk.Event.KEY_PRESS` and `Gdk.Event.KEY_RELEASE`). You can make use of `Gdk.KEY_*` to check for the value of the key which was pressed or released. You can try something on the lines of:

```
...
    def on_key_release(self, widget, ev, data=None):
        if ev.keyval == Gdk.KEY_Escape: #If Escape pressed, reset text
            widget.set_text("")
...
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        editor = Gtk.Entry()
        editor.connect("key-release-event", self.on_key_release)   
        self.add(editor)
```

There is fair amount of documentation available online to aid you.
Hope this helps!